# TypeError: position is undefined

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying to Show the Date and time with jquery-datetimepicker plugin but it's showing only Date in calender

Js Code for this is

```
$("#datetime").datetimepicker();

$("#datetimecalender").live("click", function(){
  $('#datetime').datepicker('show');
});
```

And the html for this is

```
<a id="datetimecalender" class="badge icon-calendar"></a>
<input id="datetime" class="hasDatepicker" type="hidden" name="datetime" value="" />
```

But I am getting the error in jquery:

```
TypeError: position is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle which works : http://jsfiddle.net/LmUnr/190/

Ressources used :

- https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
- https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css

**EDIT**

You can't use a `datetimepicker` object with a input type `hidden`. You could play with the input style to make it small without border like this : http://jsfiddle.net/LmUnr/192/

And modify your HTML code :

```
<input id="datetime" type="text" name="datetime" value="" />
```

Comment: Same problem..Occures. When we set the input type as hidden.

Comment: Check my last edit : you can't set an input type as hidden to use a datetimepicker object

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
<input id="datetime" class="hasDatepicker" type="hidden" name="datetime" value="" />
```

to this

```
<input id="datetime" type="hidden" name="datetime" value="" />
```

Comment: Same problem..Occures.. But when the text box is not hidden it works fine.

Comment: and also change datetimepicker to datepicker

Comment: Why would the class be a problem?!?